# Using FirebaseListAdapter in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebaseui

I'm trying to implement a `ListView` with a `FirebaseListAdapter` attached on it. I need to display a list of strings inside the adapter, so I'm using `String` as generic. The structure of the Firebase Database is this:

[image]

I need to display the keys available under the `users` node (102127..., 102133..., etc.), so I'm using this code to create the adapter:

```
val ref = db.getReference(MATCHES_REF).child(match).child(USERS_REF)
val adapter = object : FirebaseListAdapter<String>(this, String::class.java, R.layout.cell_friends, ref) {
    override fun populateView(view: View, s: String, i: Int) {
        val text = view.findViewById(R.id.text_view) as TextView
        text.text = s
    }
}
listView?.adapter = adapter
```

This is the error shown in Android Studio:

> Error:(50, 32) None of the following functions can be called with the
>   arguments supplied: public constructor FirebaseListAdapter(activity: Activity!, parser: ((DataSnapshot!) -> String!)!,
>   @LayoutRes modelLayout: Int, query: Query!) defined in
>   com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter public constructor
>   FirebaseListAdapter(activity: Activity!, parser:
>   SnapshotParser!, @LayoutRes modelLayout: Int, query: Query!)
>   defined in com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter public
>   constructor FirebaseListAdapter(activity: Activity!,
>   modelClass: Class!, @LayoutRes modelLayout: Int, query:
>   Query!) defined in com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter

Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, the first argument of the `FirebaseListAdaptwer` constructor (`this`) wasn't an `Activity` type.